# Customize 500 Error Page in DXA 1.4 Java

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-java

When a page is not found, the DXA framework initiates a redirect to the website's `error-404.html` page but I could not find any redirect's when the HTTP code is 500.

After inspecting the source code for the DXA core module I found that the following view is served when there's a 500 response: `\META-INF\resources\WEB-INF\Views\Shared\Error\ServerError.jsp`

Is there any way that I can provide my own custom view without modifying the dxa core module?

Regard,
Kunal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there is no a normal way to override the view for 500 error, there is a possible workaround to solve the issue.

Since view is resolved with a `ViewResolver` instance, you can specify your own view resolver. There are two ways to do this:

1. Create a bean of `ViewResolver` interface and mark it as primary. Then Spring should use it instead of default one. You can then inject some 'special' logic to catch the `ServerError.jsp` resolve process, and return your custom. 
   I would prefer the second way though, because I am not sure how Spring will load all beans of ViewResolver, and because this way will break device-specific view resolver coming with DXA 1.5.
2. Create an additional `ViewResolver` which will be called before a default one. Although, since default comes without an explicit `order` I am still not sure whether this will work properly. Anyway you can try something like this:

   ```
   @Bean
   public ViewResolver yourViewResolver() {
       UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver() {    
           @Override
           public View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale) throws Exception {
               if (viewName.contains("ServerError")) {
                   viewName += "-special";
               }
               return super.resolveViewName(viewName, locale);
           }
       };

       viewResolver.setViewClass(OptionalJstlView.class);    
       // set highest order or at least higher then the default
       viewResolver.setOrder(org.springframework.core.Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);             
       viewResolver.setPrefix(viewResolverPrefix);
       viewResolver.setSuffix(viewResolverSuffix);
       return viewResolver;
   }
   ```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and +1 for the code sample, thanks!

Comment: Nice example @Alexey!