# Prevent this error from appearing due to invalid page requests

Tags: dxa, 2013-sp1, dxa-java, java

In Tridion 2013 we are getting generic exception for the pages that do not exist in the website.
Is there a way to prevent generic errors due to invalid page requests? 
Thanks.

Comment: Where? on your website? Which technology do you use for the website? https://serverfault.com/questions/254102/custom-error-pages-on-apache-tomcat or https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/ this may help

Comment: It is on the website developed in java

Comment: are you using DXA java? Any additional details on the web application architecture will help provide the right solution

Comment: Hi Shiva thanks for your answer. We are using DXA Java Project with Spring and Oracle 12.1 c.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent an exception or error being thrown by the application for pages or items that does not exist. However, you can customize the error message or throw errors differently to create a better user experience.

You can look through the [example](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14889/customize-500-error-page-in-dxa-1-4-java) for DXA 1.4. It should be pretty similar to the DXA version that you are using, though.

The other way would be to change the default ServerError.jsp in your web application. This would change the default error message from DXA though.